# java generic class & wildcards

Tags: java, generics

I have a Box generic class with the following feature:

- one of the 2 `put` methods should allow a client to insert a box and get its content to the current box.

I want this method to get 2 types of boxes: `Box<Number>` and  `Box<Integer>`, that is why I changed the `put(Box<T>)` method to `put(Box<? extends Number> box)`. But I get compilation warning. What am I doing wrong here?

This is my current code:
the warning i get is: Type safety: Unchecked cast from capture#1-of ? extends Number to T

```
public class Box<T> {
    public T get() {
        return element;
    }

    public void put(T element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public void put(Box<? extends Number> box) {
        put((T) box.get()); // this is where i get the warning
    }

    private T element;
}

public class BoxClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box<Number> nBox = new Box<Number>();
        Box<Integer> iBox = new Box<Integer>();
        nBox.put(iBox);

    }

}
```

Comment: When you have an error, please include the error in your question.

Comment: *"but i get compilation warning"* Can you share it?

Comment: `T` does not extend `Number`, hence the compiler warning; you're doing an unsafe cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `Box` defines a generic type `T`.
`T` can be anything. I.e. "A Box containing **any** kind of object"

Then, your method receives a `Box<? extends Number>`. I.e. "A Box containing a type of Number".

The problem is in your method:

```
public void put(Box<? extends Number> box) {
    put(box.get());
}
```

The method receives "A Box containing a number", however, it does a cast to `T`.
Remember, `T` can be anything, so you can potentially perform a cast to something that isn't actually a number. Consider this example:

```
public class BoxClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box<String> sBox = new Box<String>();
        Box<Integer> iBox = new Box<Integer>();

        iBox.put(1);
        sBox.put(iBox);

        System.out.println(sBox.get()); 
    } 

}
```

Here, I created a `Box<String>` or "A Box containing Strings" and added a `Box<Integer>` or "A Box containing a Number".
By the generics code, this is valid since `T` can be anything, however, if you try to execute it

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

That's because the `Integer` 1 cannot be cast to a `String`.

To make sure this will never happen, you need to change the declaration of `Box` to enforce that `T extends Number`, as below:

```
public class Box<T extends Number> {
    public T get() {
        return element;
    } 

    public void put(T element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public void put(Box<? extends T> box) {
        put((T) box.get());
    }

    private T element;
}
```

UPDATE:
As mentioned, my previous answer could still be unsafe.
Say, if you have a `Box<Number>` and try to add to it a `Box<Integer>`, it would still be allowed and still throw an exception.

Best solution is to add bayou.io's suggestion as well.
This way you will ensure that:
1: Your Box always contains numbers
2: Your Box can only add from other Box that extends for `T`

UPDATE2:
As mentioned below in the comments by newacct, the cast to `T` was also not necessary.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this helps very much. thank's :) just to make sure, the solution you suggested means that the generic class now only gets Numbers or its sub classes and no other types?

Comment: Precisely!
You defined that `T` no longer can be "Anything", instead, `T` can only be classes that extends Number.

Comment: If that was not what you wanted, you could use bayou.io's answer to enforce that your method will always receive something that extends `T`

Comment: Care to elaborate, instead of just downvoting?

Comment: @Sekkuar: `box.get()` will already return `T` so you don't need to cast to `T`.

Answer (score 6):

change it to

```
public void put(Box<? extends T> box) {
    put(box.get());
}
```

Comment: thank you I now get what i did wrong. appriciate the help! :)

Answer (score 3):

If I test your code, then I get a warning in this method:

```
public void put(Box<? extends Number> box) {
    put( (T) box.get());
}
```

And the warning is:

> Unchecked cast: `java.lang.Number` to `T`

The problem is that your generic type `T` has no [bounds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html), so it can be anything and due to the [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) it will be erased to `Object`.

The generic type of the variable `box` has a bound, so it is clear, that it will always be some kind of `Number`.

Your cast `(T) box.get()` is now "unsafe", because `box.get()` returns a subtype of `Number` and `T` can be anything, like a `String`. So the compile can't be sure that this cast will always be ok and won't throw a `ClassCastException`.
That is why he is warning you about your unsafe cast.

Comment: My compiler didn't give the warning though.

Answer (score 1):

Your Box has a generic type `T`, which makes no assumptions about its type (no bounds). If your box should only be able to contain `Number`s (and subtypes of `Number`), you can change it to: `class Box<T extends Number>`.
and your method to: `put(Box<? extends T> box)`, so that it accepts `T` and any subtypes of it.

Comment: what if i choose to change only the put method argument type? it means i keep the calss more generic and still my demand regarding Number and Integer is being handled no?

Comment: yes, sure. that's more generic, and also works for Number and Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem results of the fact, that generic types were introduced in Java 5. Because of that, the method signature does not contain information about 
generic classes.

Class draft:

```
public abstract class Draft<T> {
    public abstract void put(T element);
    public abstract void putDraft(Draft draft);
}
```

With this draft, the code stays readable and you don't have any compiler 
warnings.

Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) to find further information about this problem.

Comment: Your answer is very vague. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: thank's  so how do i implement a generic class with a put method that meets my needs? i'm sure i have to use wildcards im just not so sure how.